# How to split an amount of objects evenly over groups, given a maximum amount of objects per group (Java)

Tags: java

I am working on a school project in which I have an ArrayList with objects. I have to split these objects evenly over groups (other ArrayLists), with a maximum amount of objects per group(maximumGroupSize).

How do I split these objects so that they are evenely distributed over the groups, with the minimum amount of groups given the maximumGroupSize?

I have tried the following code:

```
public List<List<Object>> createGroups(List<Object> objects, int maximumGroupSize) {
    float totalObjectCount = objects.size();
    float maxGroupSize = maximumGroupSize;
    List<List<Object>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < java.lang.Math.ceil(totalObjectCount / maximumGroupSize); i++){
        List<Object> group = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = (i*maximumGroupSize); j < maximumGroupSize*(i+1);j++){
            if (j<objects.size()) {
                group.add(objects.get(j));
            }
        }
        groups.add(group);
    }
    return groups;
}
```

This will result in the first groups all having maximum capacity. But the last group that is created will contain the "leftovers".

So if I have a total list of 18 objects and maximumGroupSize = 8, it will result in two groups of 8 objects and one of 2 objects.

If possible, I would like to have the size of the groups as close to each other as possible.

So that would output three lists of 6 with the above input.

I am working in Java, so I need a way to do it in Java. Code would be great, but also a step by step way to split would be okay so I could create the code myself.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have created so far to try and solve this problem?

Comment: I have added the code that I tried above. Solved a piece of the problem on the way, but still not finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have now provided the code that you tried, here is my solution which I was not posting earlier as you had shown no attempt:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(10, 20)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> groups[] = createGroups(list, 4);
    for (List<Integer> group : groups) {
        System.out.println(group);
    }
}

public static List<Integer>[] createGroups(List<Integer> list, int maximumPerGroup) {
    int numberOfGroups = list.size() / maximumPerGroup;
    if (list.size() % maximumPerGroup > 0) numberOfGroups++;
    List<Integer> groups[] = new ArrayList[numberOfGroups];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (groups[i % numberOfGroups] == null) groups[i % list.size()] = new ArrayList<>();
        groups[i % numberOfGroups].add(list.get(i));
    }
    return groups;
}
```

**Output**

```
[10, 13, 16, 19]
[11, 14, 17]
[12, 15, 18]
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks for the solution. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're given the maximum group size allowed for the split groups, then you can use this to figure out the minimum number of groups.

This can be done by using the length of the original ArrayList. Divide the number of objects in the original list by the maximum group size, and take the ceiling of this number to get your minimum number of groups.

So for example if you're given an ArrayList of Objects that has 11 Objects in it, and your maximum group size is 2, then your minimum number of groups is 6.

From this you can now create the required number of ArrayLists required. Once you've got these ArrayLists it should be pretty easy to split the original list into these ones.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used this to create the code added in the question.